# Kivy on_copy event?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a basic text input box with some text in it. When the user attempts to copy the text, I want to execute a function that modifies the text first then returns it. An `on_copy` event would be perfect. However, I do not see an obvious way to do this in Kivy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `TextInput` subclass that overrides the `copy()` method:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:  
    MyTextInput:
    MyTextInput:
""")

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def copy(self, data=''):
        # wrap copied text with ---
        if data:
            data = "--- {} ---".format(data)
        else:
            data = "--- {} ---".format(self.selection_text)
        return super(MyTextInput, self).copy(data)

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ClientApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClientApp().run()
```

You should probably override `cut()` method too.